# Unit Testing: Is dependency between tests is a good idea at all?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, testng

I come form `JUnit` and recently started with a project where I started using `TestNG`.
One of the features that `TestNG` has that you can define the if your test depends on other tests.

This is surprising to me since I always thought that tests needs to be independent. They must create their own data, assert and move on. It sounds confusing to me.

I wanted to gather feedback if it is a good idea at all.

Comment: When you're testing a multi-step workflow, it can be a cleaner alternative to dumping a long script in a single test method. Similar for UI tests that need login and navigation.

Comment: how about having abstract unit test class which does that in separate functions?

Comment: That just means that every downstream test now needs boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion tests should be independent. As @daydreamer said, a good practice is to put some util/shared code in abstract class to simplify test code. Lets consider testing CRUD, I think the best way to test such thing is to: test create in a setup method, test read and update in usual tests and finally test delete in a cleaning method. Test result cannot be dependent on a resource (e.g. data in database).

Answer (score 1):

I do not use testNG but I think this feature might be useful sometimes.

I agree with the idea of independent tests, meaning that the data created for one test should not be used by another test in order to avoid side effects.

However, sometimes you know that if your program cannot perform a simple task A, it will not be able to perform a more complicated task B. So if test for A fails, you know test for B will also fail. For instance, I do not think I can parse a complicated json string (task/test B) if my program is not even able to parse `'{"a":1}'` (task/test A).

If you have a regression which makes the task A impossible, every more complicated operation like B will fail and the reason will not be obvious at first sight (The report will show X failed tests whereas fixing only one will solve everything). If your code contains information about dependencies, you will know directly which test is causing the problem (and the test framework won't be running tests that will surely fail).